# rosewill wireless pci card not working

Tags: 12.10, wireless, networking, atheros

Relevant specs

Rosewill RNX-N250PC2 pci wireless adapter

Biostar A780L3c motherboard

Ubuntu 12.10

On first install on 12.10, wireless card worked perfect out of the box. However, after updating system software, it no longer works. The settings are all still there in the network manager, but can't seem to get it to function.

Output of lspci -nn | grep 0280 gives:

```
Network controller [0280]: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9227 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:002d] (rev 01)
```

Output of lshw -C network gives the following

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: AR9227 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
       physical id: 5
       bus info: pci@0000:03:05.0
       version: 01
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=64
       resources: memory:febf0000-febfffff
```

Answer (score 2):

Doing a modprobe fixed it.

I had looked into this route before, but running the command `lsmod | grep ath` to find the available drives didn't give me any output, so flopped around on the net trying to find out out to get the divers... long story short, I eventually tried running the second command, which was `sudo modprobe ath9k` and again, no output, but suddenly, on the system bar it pops up that the wireless network is connected.